# Why Does Kotlin HttpsURLConnection Always Return 404

Tags: android, api, rest, kotlin, networking

Spent about 4 hours trying to figure out why below HTTP Request always gives me 404 result.  I have tried almost every permutation by commenting out specific lines.

Essentially, I am trying to get a basic example of REST api working within Kotlin Android 29.  I call below methoid in order to test out networking and 404 is always the response.

```
//url_address = "http://my-website.com/api/v1/create"
fun raw_json( url_address : String, method : String  ) {
    val req_method = method.uppercase();
    // Create JSON using JSONObject
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("name", "Jack")
    jsonObject.put("salary", "3540")
    jsonObject.put("age", "23")

    // Convert JSONObject to String
    val json_str_payload = jsonObject.toString()

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val url = URL(url_address )

        val connection =   url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection;

        Log.d("NOBILL", "Running Request with Method " + req_method)
        // Set Request Properties
        connection.requestMethod = req_method
        /*
        connection.setRequestProperty(  "Content-Type",  "application/json; charset=UTF-8"   )
        connection.setRequestProperty(  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",  "Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type"   )
        connection.setRequestProperty(  "Allow",  "*"   ) 
        connection.setRequestProperty(   "Accept-Encoding",  "gzip, deflate, br"  )
        connection.doInput = true */
        connection.doOutput = true
        if ( req_method == "POST") {
            // Send the JSON we created
            val outputStreamWriter = OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream)
            outputStreamWriter.write(json_str_payload)
            outputStreamWriter.flush()
        }

        Log.d("NOBILL", "Awaiting Response " + req_method)
        // Check if the connection is successful
        val responseCode = connection.responseCode

        if (responseCode == 200) {
            val response = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader() .use { it.readText() }  // defaults to UTF-8
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

                val res_string = JSONTokener(response).nextValue() as String ;
                Log.d("NOBILL :", res_string )
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("NOBILL", responseCode.toString() + " " + req_method+":"+url_address)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your API is POST or GET method?

Comment: What does 404 mean?

Comment: A **404** response code means you've *talked to the server* and the server *can't find the resource you've requested*. So it *is* connecting, but the server doesn't have what you're asking for. Generally 404 means the *URL* is bad, but it *could* also mean that the query you've used hasn't resulted in any content being found - depends on the service implementation

Comment: Out of interest though, I notice your URL is **http** and not **https**, and you have to explicitly opt-in to *http* cleartext traffic: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html Any chance it's being rewritten as a *https* call and your server treats that as a missing page?